# How to add excel file to QTableWidget without erasing its column and data?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

How do i load excel data to QTableWidget? I want it to appear after the last recipient data

[image: this is my columns and data]

[image: This is when i import my excel file.]

This is the code i used:

```
 def addExcel(self, excel_file_dir, worksheet_name):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_dir, worksheet_name)
    if df.size == 0:
            return 

    df.fillna('', inplace=True)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df.shape[1])

    for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]
            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                    if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                            value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                    tableItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation of [`setRowCount()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setRowCount) explains:

> Sets the number of rows in this table's model to rows. If this is less than rowCount(), the data in the unwanted rows is discarded.

The same clearly goes for `setColumnCount()` as well.

If you want to preserve existing data, you obviously have to *add* the row and column count based on the new data.

Considering that data models usually increase the number of records (*rows*) while keeping the columns, you have to call `setRowCount()` by increasing the *current* row count by the number of new records, and set the column count based on the *maximum* between the existing column count and the retrieved one.

```py
def addExcel(self, excel_file_dir, worksheet_name):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_dir, worksheet_name)
    if df.size == 0:
            return 

    df.fillna('', inplace=True)

    newFirstRow = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(newFirstRow + df.shape[0])
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(
        max(self.tableWidget.columnCount(), df.shape[1]))

    for rowData in df.iterrows():
        row = newFirstRow + rowData[0]
        values = rowData[1]
        for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
            if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, col_index, tableItem)
```

<sup>Note: `'{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)` is quite pointless in most cases: you can just use `str(round(value))` instead.</sup>